# Send list of object from view to controller on submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, view, controller, viewbag

I'm creating an array of string dynamically and I want when click on sumbit button to send this array to the controller
I created this array with jquery
how to do that? is it possible to write in viewbag from vien
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Arrays(string[][] arrays)
{
    // Do something with the arrays
    return Json(new { status = "success" });
}
```

and to post:

```
var arrays = [{'0':'value1', '1':'value2'}, 
          {'0':'value3', '1':'value4'},
          {'0':'value5', '1':'value6'}];
$.post('/home/arrays', { arrays: arrays }, function(result) {
    alert(result.status);        
});
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it,just how to schedule the post when submiting